# Выдаёт ошибку при попытке создать png файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pyqrcode


qr = pyqrcode.create('https://www.instagram.com/armanchev/')
qr.png('d:\\Download\\qr3.png', scale=60, background='green')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Docs\pycharm\autopress\main.py", line 5, in <module>
qr.png('d:\\Download\\qr3.png', scale=60, background='green')
File "D:\Docs\pycharm\autopress\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\__init__.py", line 462, in png builder._png(self.code, self.version, file, scale,
File "D:\Docs\pycharm\autopress\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\builder.py", line 1266, in _png import png
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'png'
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка означает, что у вас не установлен указанный модуль:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'png'
```

[В документации к модулю pyqrcode](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/#usage) есть об этом указание:

> If you install the optional **pypng library**, you can also render the
> code as a PNG image

Похоже, имеется ввиду эта библиотека: https://pypi.org/project/pypng/

Нужно установить её:

```
pip install pypng
```